# wxPython StaticText escaping nested BoxSizer

Tags: wxpython, boxsizer

Full-disclosure: I am new to wxpython (about 3 days) and I don't really understand the finer points of boxsizers.

I'm writing a GUI to display a photo and some associated details about it. I am using box sizers to display 3 "sections" horizontally on the main tab. The leftmost item is an image preview, the middle item displays some info, and the rightmost has a StaticText title and two radio buttons. Somehow the StaticText appears to be escaping its BoxSizer. I've colored the different sections garish colors to make it more obvious:
[image: escaped panel item]

Here's the relevant section of code:

```python
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.loadContents()

    def loadContents(self):
        self.loadPreview()
        self.loadImageInfo()
        self.loadColorOptions()

        row0 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        row0.Add(self.preview, 1, wx.LEFT, 5)
        row0.Add(self.imageInfo, 1, wx.EXPAND , 5)
        row0.Add(self.colorPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(row0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def loadColorOptions(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour((230,230,230))
        self.title = wx.StaticText(self, label="Options", style=wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.radioButtonColor = wx.RadioButton(panel, label="Color", style=wx.RB_GROUP)
        self.radioButtonGray = wx.RadioButton(panel, label="Grayscale")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.title, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.radioButtonColor, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.radioButtonGray, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.colorPanel = panel
```

And the full context:

```python
import wx 
from wx.lib.wordwrap import wordwrap
import os

from mock_utils import *

ICON_STR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'flower.ico')
INITIAL_SIZE_X = 1000
INITIAL_SIZE_Y = 700
SCALE_RATIO = 100
PREVIEW_SIZE = [4*SCALE_RATIO, 3*SCALE_RATIO] # 4:3
TITLE="Photo GUI"

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.loadContents()

    def loadContents(self):
        self.loadPreview()
        self.loadImageInfo()
        self.loadColorOptions()

        row0 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        row0.Add(self.preview, 1, wx.LEFT, 5)
        row0.Add(self.imageInfo, 1, wx.EXPAND , 5)
        row0.Add(self.colorPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(row0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def loadColorOptions(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour((230,230,230))
        self.title = wx.StaticText(self, label="Options", style=wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.radioButtonColor = wx.RadioButton(panel, label="Color", style=wx.RB_GROUP)
        self.radioButtonGray = wx.RadioButton(panel, label="Grayscale")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.title, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.radioButtonColor, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.radioButtonGray, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.colorPanel = panel

    def loadPreview(self):
        fname = getImage()
        self.imageInfo = getImageInfo(fname)
        if fname is not None:
            img = wx.Image(fname, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
            img = img.Scale(PREVIEW_SIZE[0],PREVIEW_SIZE[1], wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        else:
            img = wx.Image(PREVIEW_SIZE)

        self.preview = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(img))

    def loadImageInfo(self):
        imgInfo = wx.StaticText(self, style=wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        infoStr = wordwrap("Filename:\n" + "\t" + self.imageInfo.get("name") + \
                "\nSettings:\n" + "\t" + "Exposure: " + self.imageInfo.get("exposure") + \
                           "\n" + "\t" + "Focus: " + self.imageInfo.get("focus"), 350, wx.ClientDC(self))

        imgInfo.SetLabel(infoStr)
        imgInfo.SetBackgroundColour("yellow")
        self.imageInfo = imgInfo

class Panel2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

class PhotoGuiFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, title=TITLE, size=(INITIAL_SIZE_X,INITIAL_SIZE_Y))
        self.SetIcon(wx.Icon(ICON_STR, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO, 16, 16))
        self.Center() # center gui on screen

        self.loadPanels()

    def loadPanels(self):

        p = wx.Panel(self)
        dock = wx.Notebook(p)
        main_panel = MainPanel(dock)
        panel2 = Panel2(dock)

        dock.AddPage(main_panel, "Tab1")
        dock.AddPage(panel2, "Tab2")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(dock, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = PhotoGuiFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And a bare-bones mock_utils.py  if you want a minimal "working" example (will display a blank box instead of loading an image):

```python
pth1 = "/home/wxnewbie/Desktop/gui/test/images/img"

def getImage():
    return None

def getImageInfo(fname):
    return {"name": pth1+"2.tif", "exposure":"1.5ms", "focus":"automatic"}
```

I am completely at a loss as to why the StaticText is escaping the BoxSizer. The only thing I've been able to come up with is that I need to get rid of the panel that it's attached to (in which case, do I return the sizer itself?). But I then run into the trouble of the items in the sizer disappearing entirely, so I think I'm just missing some basic bit of info about how sizers are supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a classic, can't see the woods for the trees, issue.
You are placing `self.title` in `self` not in the panel.

This should fix the problem.

`self.title = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Options", style=wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_MULTILINE)`

Comment: I can't believe I missed it, but you're totally correct; thank you! It works perfectly now.